# Android Espresso - Clicking on the first RecyclerView Item with a certain string after swipeUp to ending of list

Tags: android, scroll, click, android-espresso

Basically, Espresso scrollTo doesn't work on this view, so to assert that an item was created, I must swipeUp to end of list and check the first item with certain string.
That item is the result of another test where the item is created. It's normal for that item to be repeated several times depending on how many tests were run before.
Right now I can't click on item because either it's not fully visible or there's more than one of them.
I managed to resolve both issues seperatly in different cases but not at the same time on this one.

I use for this code from stackoverflow for avoiding more than one similar view exception:

```
public class FirstViewMatcher extends BaseMatcher {

public static boolean matchedBefore = false;

public FirstViewMatcher() {
    matchedBefore = false;
}

@Override
public boolean matches(Object item) {
    if (matchedBefore) {
        return false;
    } else {
        matchedBefore = true;
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void describeTo(Description description) {
    description.appendText(" first similar view to appear.");
}

@Factory
public static <T> Matcher<View> firstView() {
    return new FirstViewMatcher();
}
```

And also use this code on the perform click, so that view needs not be fully visible.

```
ViewInteraction scrollView = onView(withId(R.id.ptr_layout));
    scrollView.perform(swipeUp(), swipeUp());
ViewInteraction testItem= onView(
            allOf(withText("Favorite Test"),
                    FirstViewMatcher.firstView()));
    testItem.check(matches(allOf(isEnabled(), isClickable()))).perform(
            new ViewAction() {
                @Override
                public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
                    return ViewMatchers.isDisplayingAtLeast(1); // no constraints, they are checked above
                }

                @Override
                public String getDescription() {
                    return "clicking not fully visible item";
                }

                @Override
                public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
                    view.performClick();
                }
            }
    );
```

I get this error:

```
E/TestRunner: failed: a_CheckFavoriteDetails(ca.com.android.celero.Public.ACU_E_CheckFavoriteDetails)
----- begin exception -----
E/TestRunner: androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: '(is enabled and is clickable)' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: (is enabled and is clickable)
     Got: "AppCompatTextView{id=2131362475, res-name=favourite_list_item_description, visibility=VISIBLE, width=837, height=50, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@83ce175, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=165.0, y=46.0, text=Favorite Test, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"

    at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1720)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:96)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:59)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:324)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:306)
    at ca.com.android.celero.Public.ACU_E_CheckFavoriteDetails.a_CheckFavoriteDetails(ACU_E_CheckFavoriteDetails.java:166)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:61)
    at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:531)
    at androidx.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule$RequestPermissionStatement.evaluate(GrantPermissionRule.java:134)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:395)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2189)
 Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: '(is enabled and is clickable)' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: (is enabled and is clickable)
     Got: "AppCompatTextView{id=2131362475, res-name=favourite_list_item_description, visibility=VISIBLE, width=837, height=50, has-focus=false, has-fo
----- end exception -----
```

Answer (score 0):

`ViewActions.scrollTo` only works on `ScrollView` and `ViewActions.swipeUp` can be flaky when used on `RecyclerView`. `FirstViewMatcher` is not a good solution as it will only work the first time use. You got the error because you expected the `TextView` to be clickable but it's not.

Instead, you should consider [RecyclerViewActions](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions.html?hl=en) to perform tests on your `RecyclerView`:

```
onView(R.id.your_recycler_view)
    .perform(actionOnItemAtPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(0, click())
```

`RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition` will scroll to the position, then perform the action.

Comment: Will try this one. The main problem is that the app wasn't built for scalability and it has scaled quite a bit, also, this tests are being studied to apply to the app only now. Also, most views are custom made, making most view actions not work right. The app construction makes it incredibly hard to test anything and most espresso methods won't work there. Also, position changes randomly sometimes when a new one is added or removed.

Comment: I can only explain why you got the error, and suggest how to avoid it. Anything else would be considered off-topic. Good luck!